# I just purchased this painting and I need some information

Tags: translation

Hello I need help with these symbols and calligraphy. I purchased the painting on a flea market for my husband. We don'[image]t have a clue as to what it says but I would love to find out about the story on the painting. thank you

Comment: These seals aren’t anything to do with the painting or text on the painting. They’re basically ugly stamps by past Emperors claiming the artwork as part of their treasure.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> 1. 漢光閣顧洛阜鑑藏中國古代書畵章
>
>    *Stamp of authenticity of John M. Crawford's collection of old Chinese art*
> 2. 乾隆鑑賞
>
>    *[Qianlong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qianlong_Emperor) likes this*
> 3. 嘉慶御覽㞢寶
>
>    *Certified as seen by [Jiaqing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiaqing_Emperor)*
> 4. 三希堂精鑑璽
>
>    *Refined seal of the library of the [Qing Emperors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emperors_of_the_Qing_dynasty)*
> 5. 南北東西只有相隨無別離
>
>    *No parting ways, only companionship, on any road*
> 6. 敵國㞢富
>
>    *As wealthy as an empire*

Comment: the fourth one, "might be" "三希堂精鑑璽"